# How to feed appium with right parameters?

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm trying to connect to Android emulator with a following capabilities:

```
public class SimpleAndroidCalcTest {

 WebDriver driver;

 @Before public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
     capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "android-7");
     capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
     capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
```

And keep getting following bad parameters error:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","platformVersion":"7.1.1","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"android-7"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","platformVersion":"7.1.1","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"android-7"},"requiredCapabilities":{}},"alwaysMatch":{"appPackage":"com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","platformVersion":"7.1.1","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"android-7"},"firstMatch":[]}
[MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","capabilities","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities","capabilities","alwaysMatch","firstMatch"]
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 4 ms - 243
```

I've checked many times input capabilities, they seem to be valid, as far I can tell, or should I use something else?

Appium server: v1.6.4
selenium-java: v3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because you are using the selenium-java : v3.3.1 without the correct Appium java client

Please refer to : https://github.com/appium/java-client

only from the latest appium java client 5.0.0-BETA7 it is possible to use selenium-java : v3.3.1.

or you can revert selenium-java back to 2.53.1